# Conditional expectation with “or” in condition

Tags: logic, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

For random variables $X$ and $Y$, I would like to simplify expression $E[X \, \vert \, Y = y_1 \, \lor \, Y = y_2]$.
Idea is getting rid of *"or"* statement from condition of expectation.

Is this statement valid?
\begin{aligned}
E[X \, \vert \, Y = y_1 \, \lor \, Y = y_2] &= E[X \, \vert \, Y = y_1] \cdot P[Y = y_1 \, \vert \, Y = y_1 \, \lor \, Y = y_2] \\
&+ E[X \, \vert \, Y = y_2] \cdot P[Y = y_2 \, \vert \, Y = y_1 \, \lor \, Y = y_2]
\end{aligned}

Comment: I think it is (for $y_1 \neq y_2$). Here was my starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event

Comment: Yeah I thought so too. It is probably just an example of Law of Total Expectation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

Comment: PS: Assuming $Y$ is discrete random variable, so that $P(Y=y_1\mid Y=y_1\vee Y=y_2)$ is sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Basically, when $U$ and $V$ are *disjoint* events, with non-zero measure: $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X\mid U\cup V)&=\dfrac{\mathsf E(X\mathbf 1_{U\cup V})}{\mathsf P(U\cup V)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf E(X\mathbf 1_U)+\mathsf E(X\mathbf 1_V)}{\mathsf P(U\cup V)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf E(X\mid U)\,\mathsf P(U)+\mathsf E(X\mid V)\,\mathsf P(V)}{\mathsf P(U\cup V)}\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(X\mid U)\,\mathsf P(U\mid U\cup V)+\mathsf E(X\mid V)\,\mathsf P(V\mid U\cup V)\end{align}$$

---

It is just the Law of Total Expectation applied over a conditioning event. So when $y_1\neq y_2$.

$$\mathsf E(X\mid Y{\in}\{y_1,y_2\})= {\mathsf E(X\mid Y{=}y_1)\mathsf P(Y{=}y_1\mid Y{\in}\{y_1,y_2\})+\mathsf E(X\mid Y{=}y_1)\mathsf P(Y{=}y_1\mid Y{\in}\{y_1,y_2\})}$$

Comment: Great, so we can even write (for $y_1 \neq y_2$):
$$E[X \, \vert \, Y = y_1 \, \lor \, Y = y_2] = \frac{E[X \, \vert \, Y = y_1] \cdot P[Y = y_1] + E[X \, \vert \, Y = y_2] \cdot P[Y = y_2]}{P[Y = y_1 \, \lor \, Y = y_2]}$$
Correct?

Comment: Yes.  If those probabilities are not zero. @matt525252